# Facebook Messenger Payments

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm looking for a way to integrate Facebook's peer to peer payments for messenger into an iOS application. Does Facebook have a public API for this service or should I use a different third party service like Venmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to say you will have to go with a third party in this case. Facebook's Help Page states that messenger payments will only be for friends and family and never for businesses.

See [the page here](https://www.facebook.com/help/294045524131594) for more information.